# Problem saving HTML link inside Wordpress wp_options table

Tags: php, wordpress, textarea

I'm saving some extra information on each `wordpress tag` using an `textarea` field and a function:

**This is the `textarea` field (using `stripslashes`):**

```
<textarea name="Tag_meta[related_links]" id="Tag_meta[related_links]" size="25" placeholder="enter here the links html"><?php echo stripslashes($tag_meta['related_links'] ? $tag_meta['related_links'] : ''); ?></textarea>
```

**This is the saving function:**

```
add_action ( 'edit_term', 'save_termmeta_tag');
   // save extra category extra fields callback function
function save_termmeta_tag( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['Tag_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $tag_meta = get_option( "tag_$t_id");
        $tag_keys = array_keys($_POST['Tag_meta']);
            foreach ($tag_keys as $key){
            if (isset($_POST['Tag_meta'][$key])){
                $tag_meta[$key] = $_POST['Tag_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        //save the option array
        update_option( "tag_$t_id", $tag_meta );
    }
}
```

The problem is that **in one** of those saved fields (in `wp_options` table), I have a bit of `HTML` and the problem resides on the `link` inside of that `HTML`.

As you can see on the example bellow, this is the `HTML` entered on the `textarea` field (before saving the form):

```
<li><a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="https://www.blablabla.com/the-rest-of-the-link">link</a></li>
```

This is the way it's being saved in `wp_options` table:

```
<li><a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.blablabla.com/the-rest-of-the-link\">link</a></li>
```

**Please note**: The saving process also ads extra's `\` each time I save the options. eg:

**Saving one**:

```
<li><a rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://www.blablabla.com/the-rest-of-the-link\">link</a></li>
```

**Saving two**:

```
<li><a rel=\\\"nofollow\\\" target=\\\"_blank\\\" href=\\\"https://www.blablabla.com/the-rest-of-the-link\\\">link</a></li>
```

etc..

And this is the way it's being outputed (by the `echo`):

```
http://www.mydomainname.com/https://www.blablabla.com/the-rest-of-the-link\"
```

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried using `htmlentities()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) when saving?

Comment: @Bossman Tried! thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately It's not working also. But... should I use the `htmlentities()` on the saving `function` **OR** in the `<textarea` by replacing the `stripslashes()`?

Comment: Try: `update_option('your_option', htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['tag_meta'])));` when saving. When reading try using `html_entity_decode(get_option('your_option'));`.

Comment: @Bossman I didn't tried your sugestion but it made me think and I would like to know your opinion on this working solution:

**I replace this on the textarea**:
`<?php echo stripslashes($tag_meta['related_links'] ? $tag_meta['related_links'] : ''); ?>`

**by this one**: `<?php echo stripslashes($tag_meta['related_links'] ? stripslashes($tag_meta['related_links']) : ''); ?>`

**and on the `echo` I did this**: `echo stripslashes($tag_meta['related_links']);`

It works, but I would like opinios to know if it can be done this way... Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

**Replace this on the textarea**:

`<?php echo stripslashes($tag_meta['related_links'] ? $tag_meta['related_links'] : ''); ?>`

**by this**:

`<?php echo stripslashes($tag_meta['related_links'] ? $tag_meta['related_links']) : ''; ?>`

and on the `echo` do this:

`echo stripslashes($tag_meta['related_links']);`

**Edited**:

Answer corrected with great contribution of [@bossman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3585143/bossman)

Comment: I see now. It is because its a ternary operator. you don't need the `stripslashes()` in the condition `echo $tag_meta['related_links'] ? stripslashes($tag_meta['related_links']) : '');` will work. You are basically asking a question, if `$tag_meta['related_links']` evaluates to true then do this otherwise do that. `$result = $condition ? 'foo' : 'bar';`